# How to update the value of tabs on scrolling

Tags: android, tabs

I have implemented tab layout in android.I have 3 tabs-settings, clock, lost devices. While scrolling, the contents of tab get updated, but not the headings.But if I chose any tab heading, the content get displayed. 
When I start the app, it shows 3 tabs. Suppose current highlighted tab is clock. When I scroll right, the contents of settings tab is displayed, but the current highlighted tab is still clock. It should be settings as per my need.

my code is
This is the main activity->

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{

    //This is our tablayout
    private TabLayout tabLayout;

    //This is our viewPager
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Adding toolbar to the activity
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Initializing the tablayout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("clock"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("settings"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("lost devices"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        //Initializing viewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        //Creating our pager adapter
        Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        //Adding adapter to pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

Pager->

```
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    //integer to count number of tabs
    int tabCount;

    //Constructor to the class
    public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
        super(fm);
        //Initializing tab count
        this.tabCount= tabCount;
    }

    //Overriding method getItem
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                clock tab1 = new clock();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                settings tab2 = new settings();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                map tab3 = new map();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    //Overriden method getCount to get the number of tabs
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer may help you. [Tab change on scroll.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77717069/2289835)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to TabLayout and ViewPager is separate each other. You need to update their status in case of one of them make change. You have done with update ViewPager status when tab is selected. But vice versa you need to update Tablayout when ViewPager scroll.

1. Add listener for viewPager: `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);`. It will require you implement some methods.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // don't use in that's case
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       // update Tablayout here
       TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
       if (tab != null) {
          tab.select();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
      // don't use in that's case
   }
   ```
2. Don't forget to remove the listener if no longer use it

   ```
   viewPager.removeOnPageChangeListener(this);
   ```

Hope it help !

Comment: instead of passing this to onPageScrollStateChanged create a new instance and it worked

Comment: Both will work I'm sure. But I suggest you should prefer to use this(or declare new object instance of OnPageChangListener) and pass it in order to remove the listener if no longer use it. If you create new instance like viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {...} then you can not to remove it. That's is the bad code should avoid to

Comment: can you please comment on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160575/bluetooth-class-in-android-is-not-doing-desired-function-how-to-create-instanc

Answer (score -1):

you have setup your viewpager with tab layout. add this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    .....
    ......
    ....

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
}
```