# how to implement BlueTooth class; what should it extend; compile errors at startActivityForResult and registerReceiver

Tags: android

I have created one tab layout in main activity. It sets 3 tabs. In settings tab(which is extending ListFragment) I am handling click event on list. When 1st element is clicked, it creates BlueTooth object bt. Bluetooth extends activity.Inside that I am handling bluetooth functions.But bluetooth functions do not seem to be called.
Pasting the code
settings tab

```
   //Our class extending fragment
    public class settings extends ListFragment /*Fragment*/implements OnItemClickListener {
        String[] title = {
                "Register",
                "Set Password",
                "Edit Password",
                "Delete Password",
                "Add location to turn-off place list",
                "Disable turn-off Places",
                "Enable turn-off Places",
                "Edit Distance",
                "Factory Reset"
        };

        List<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> mDevices = new ArrayList<String>();

        String[] strings = new String[mStrings.size()];
        //Overriden method onCreateView
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            //Returning the layout file after inflating
            //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++) {
                mStrings.add(title[i]);

            }
            strings = mStrings.toArray(strings);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mStrings));
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            switch(position)
            {
                case 0:

                    Intent intent = new              Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), BlueTooth.class);
startActivity(Intent intent);
                    mDevices.add("Dev1");
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            mDevices));
                    break;
                .....



            }
        }
    }
```

Bluetooth class:

```
public class BlueTooth extends Activity {

    private BluetoothAdapter mBTA;
    private SignBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    boolean discoverFlag = false;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //register local BT adapter
        mBTA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        //check to see if there is BT on the Android device at all
        if (mBTA == null) {
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Bluetooth on this handset", duration).show();
        }
        //let's make the user enable BT if it isn't already
        /*if (!mBTA.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBT = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBT, 0xDEADBEEF);
        }*/
        Intent discoverableIntent =
                new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent,0);

        if(discoverFlag) {
            //cancel any prior BT device discovery
            if (mBTA.isDiscovering()) {
                mBTA.cancelDiscovery();
            }
            //re-start discovery
            mBTA.startDiscovery();

            //let's make a broadcast receiver to register our things
            mReceiver = new SignBroadcastReceiver();
            IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println(resultCode);
        if (resultCode ==  RESULT_CANCELED) {
            System.out.println("one");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " +  RESULT_CANCELED, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            System.out.println("two");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + -1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            discoverFlag= true;
        }
    }
}
```

Atleast the discovery user interface should show.But it is not showing.
I think I need to pass an intent while creating Bluetooth object.How to do that? I have added Activity class because I saw it in an example code. In normal class bluetooth functions are not getting implemented. It shows compiler errors.

manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.root.securityalert">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="BlueTooth"/>
        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    </manifest>
```

I fixed the code. Now it launches the intent. But I have another problem, launching activity creates a new UI which I do not want.I want to use the previous UI of ListFragment class. So, what should I extend the BlueTooth class from? using plain BlueTooth class gives compile errors at 1.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter); and 2.startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent,0);
3.@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)

Comment: Don't call new on Activity. Activities are supposed to be instantiated by the system when you pass the relevant intent. Create a regular object instead. Refer to Bluetooth documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html and activities here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html. First, Please familiarise yourself with the basics of Android first.

Comment: You need to harness more about Android  fundamental. Go to Android Developer official site to consolidate your knowledge first. About your problem, there are nothing to show due to the first you start BlueTooth activity in a wrong way, it should use Intent. The second is you have not declared BlueTooth activity in manifest file yet.

Comment: I fixed the code. Now it launches  the intent. But I have another problem, launching activity creates a new UI which I do not want.I want to use the previous UI of ListFragment class. So, what should I extend the BlueTooth class from? using plain BlueTooth class gives compile errors at 1.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, ifilter); and 2.startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent,0);

Comment: and compile error at 3.@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)